# Before Binding event?

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there an event that fires before the window has loaded and before any bindings take place?

Answer (score 1):

You can use constructor of the Window to run code before window loaded and bindings take place. However if you need an event Initialized event of the window will work for you.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    // Here it is...

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have specific event  but you can nevertheless capture the event of change of the value of control.
For example for a `TextBox`, you can subscribe to `OnTextChanged`.
He is executed before update source.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Window.Initialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.initialized.aspx) event.